# Constraining a record type in Idris

Tags: record, typeclass, idris

I am trying to write a record in Idris but that has a generic parameter which needs to be constrained by an interface.  For normal union types I can write:

```
data BSTree : (a : Type) -> Type where
  Empty : Ord a => BSTree a
  Node  : Ord a => BSTree a -> a -> BSTree a
```

but I am trying to figure out the syntax for doing the same thing, just with a record.  I tried something like:

```
record Point a where
  constructor MkPoint : Eq a => a -> a -> Point a
  x : a
  y : a
```

but it does not compile.

Is there a way to do this in Idris?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
record Point a where
  constructor MkPoint
  x : Eq a => a
  y : Eq a => a
```

Though actually you **shouldn't** do it. Instead it's better to use some smart constructor, some other function like `mkPoint : Eq a => a -> a -> MkPoint a`.
In real life you don't need to constrain types of fields for data type. Read about `-XDataTypeContexts` Haskell extension.

Comment: Thanks.  I know you *should* not add constraints directly on the fields.  That is why in my record example I tried to add the constraint to the MkPoint data constructor (which is what I am also doing for the union type).  Is there no way for me to have the constraint on the MkPoint data constructor?

Comment: @RouanvanDalen No, there's no way to add constraints directly to constructor. And there's no actual sense in it because there's no semantic difference between having constraints on fields and having constraints on `constructor`. Only syntactic difference.

Comment: But you can add a field `{auto dict : Eq a}` to the record, right?